# I am having problem using jquery for validation with bootstrap please how do I solve $ undefined and is there anything wrong with my code?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to know how to solve $ undefined in the jquery code. And if anything is wrong with my code because I am not getting results

This is part of the form

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="InputEmail1" class="col-sm-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="errormessageemail"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Firstname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        var valid = true;

        if(firstname === ""){
            valid = false;
            $("#errormessagefirstname").html("Firstname is required");
        }else{
            $("#messagefirstname").html("Looks good");
        }

        if(email === ""){
            valid = false;
            $("#errormessageemail").html("Email is reqiured");
        }else{
            $("messageemail").html("Looks good");
        }
```

Comment: Try changing `$(document).ready(function()` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`. If you then get `jQuery undefined` you are trying to use it before the library is loaded or the path to jQuery.js is wrong

Comment: This is the sequence I used in loading my jquery lib and files

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/reg.js"></script>